# JS SDK Playlists, play them one after another

Tags: deezer

I'm building a custom player for my site and it loads a playlist, my question is: Can I load automatically another playlist after the first one is over? I looked in the events and in the player's controls and I can't find a way.

I tried player_paused but it works only when you hit the pause button, not when the player stops.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the track_end event, that will be triggered at the end of each track. You can just check the track ID that ended to know if it's the end of the playlist.